# NSInvalidArgumentException with "stringwithformat"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, stringwithformat

I'm trying to write in an array, but I have the problem "NSInvalidArgumentException"

I'm beginning in objective C.

Here's a part of my code :

```
int charIndex;
unichar testChar1, testChar2;
NSString *valeur1, *valeur2;
NSMutableArray* tableau1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
NSMutableArray* tableau2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];

for(charIndex=0; charIndex < 4; charIndex++) {

    testChar1 = [_saisie.text characterAtIndex:charIndex];
    testChar2 = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", nombreChoisi] characterAtIndex:charIndex];

    NSLog(@"%C", testChar1);

    valeur1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", testChar1];
    valeur2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", testChar2];

    [tableau1 replaceObjectAtIndex:charIndex withObject:valeur1];
    [tableau2 replaceObjectAtIndex:charIndex withObject:valeur2];  
}
```

Everything is working until the line 14, where the variable `valeur1` take the value `nil`. 
I don't know where the problem is.

Edit : The line NSLog was just here to test the { @"%C", value } and it works. The value "nombreChoisi" is chosen before with a random function, and "_saisie.text" comes from a text field.

Comment: What are the values of `_saisie.text` and `nombreChoisi`? What does your log statement print out?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a capital %C when building valeur1 and valeur2.  Shouldn't you be using a lower case %c?

Comment: %C is acceptable value in `stringWithFormat:` argument. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943-SW2

Comment: I totally missed that the character variable was declared as unichar which technically does make the capital C correct: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1